# Java List "zipping"

Tags: java, list

I have the class Pair:

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {

    T1 info1;
    T2 info2;
    Pair<T1,T2> next;
    Pair<T1,T2> prev;

    Pair(T1 info1,T2 info2,Pair<T1,T2> next, Pair<T1,T2> prev) {
        this.info1 = info1;
        this.info2 = info2;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return info1.toString() + info2.toString();
    }
}
```

I must implement a class `Zipper`, that has two static methods: zip and unzip.

zip is 'zipping' two lists into one and unzipp from one in two.

For example when I have the two lists:

```
list1: 1 , 2 ,3 ,4
list2: a, b, c, d
```

zip must return : `1a, 2b, 3c, 4d` and unzip must reverse that.

I have no idea how to do that, can someone help me out?

Comment: (1) Your `Pair` class is not only a 2-tuple, it's also a doubly-linked list. You may want to consider seperating those concerns (if you have control over the class). (2) You may want to be careful with the term `Zipper` as that's already taken by a (vastly more complex and clever) functional data structure.

Comment: Given this is homework, you would get the best help if you actually wrote what the question you were given was. Otherwise completely helpful answers like @zacheusz below might miss constraints that you are operating under.

Answer (score 4):

1. don't implement your own LinkedList - this work is already done (iteration is done, etc.)
2. make Pair only 2-tuple
   So then you can implement method like this (be careful I wrote it here, in browser - so there may be typos):

Zipper:

---

```
public class Zipper {

    static <T1, T2> List<Pair<T1, T2>> zip(List<T1> input1, List<T2> input2){
        int inputSize = input1.size();
        if(inputSize != input2.size()){
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Different input sizes.");
        }
        List<Pair<T1,T2>> output = new LinkedList<Pair<T1,T2>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; ++i){
           output.add(new Pair<T1,T2>(input1.get(i), input2.get(i)));
        }
        return output;
    }

    static <T1,T2> Pair<List<T1>, List<T2>> unzip(List<Pair<T1, T2>> input){
        List<T1> output1 = new LinkedList<T1>();
        List<T2> output2 = new LinkedList<T2>();
        for(Pair<T1, T2> pair : input){
            output1.add(pair.getInfo1());
            output2.add(pair.getInfo2());
        }
        return new Pair<List<T1>, List<T2>>(output1, output2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> input1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
        List<Character> input2 = Arrays.asList('a','b','c','d');
        List<Pair<Integer, Character>> zipped = zip(input1, input2);
        System.out.println("zipped: " + zipped);
        Pair<List<Integer>,List<Character>> output = unzip(zipped);
        System.out.println("unzipped1: " + output.getInfo1());
        System.out.println("unzipped2: " + output.getInfo2());
    }
}
```

---

Pair:

---

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {
    T1 info1;
    T2 info2;

    public Pair(T1 info1, T2 info2) {
        this.info1 = info1;
        this.info2 = info2;
    }

    public T1 getInfo1() {
        return info1;
    }

    public T2 getInfo2() {
        return info2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return info1.toString() + info2.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear from your question, but I think that your example would be more usefully written (where [] means list and Pair means an object constructed by "new Pair(x, y)"):

```
Input: 
 list1: [1, 2, 3, 4]
 list2: [a, b, c, d]
Output:
   zip: [Pair<1, a>, Pair<2, b>, Pair<3, c>, Pair<4, d>]
```

That is, you end you end up with a list of pairs.

What's not clear to me is whether (as delnan points out) that you have to create a linked list or not. What are the signatures of zip and unzip you've been asked to write?

Comment: yes, i must create a linked list. zip and unzip doesn't have signatures

Comment: _All_ methods have signatures.  The signature is the list of argument types and the return type.  For example, I would guess that the signature of method `zip` is `List<T> zip(List<A>,List<A>)`.  The critical question is the types `T` and `A`.  If `A` is `String`, is `T` also String, where each list element contains the concatenation of elements from each list?  Or, is it a composite type such as `Pair<A,A>`.

Comment: Another question is whether the signature is `List<T> zip(List<A>,List<B>)` where the types of the lists differ, which then leads to the question of how `T` relates to `A` and `B` (is `T` just `Pair<A,B>` or something else).